# XSLT:Can I update value in xml node using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

For example I have a xml like

```
 <books>
   <book id="1">
     <title id="11" name="Basic XML"/>
     <price id="12" amount="500"/>
     <quantity id="13" number="10"/>
   </book>
 </books>
```

Can update the name of the book "Basic XML" to "Basic XSLT" or change any other attributes of any node using XSLT? If yes, can anyone give me some examples on how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: XSLT is used to _transform_ XML files to a different format - sounds like overkill for what you want.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution that is based on the most fundamental XSLT design pattern -- the use and overriding of the identity rule/template. Extensive explanation is also provided.

Comment: @sprenna: It's posible as @Dimitre's answer shows... But I agree with @Oded: For value replacement I would select the nodes with XPath and use the proper DOM method.

Comment: @Alejandro: EEEEEEEWWWWWW . . .

Comment: @Dimitre: Best approach really depends on what it's the meaning of "update". If that means "take an XML and serialize other XML document" from say... command line, I would go with XSLT. But if this is more general like those database questions or javascript DOM or any embedded environment where you or XSLT processor have to invoke a parser, perform the "update" and then serialize, I would go with XPath selection and DOM update. Of course, more complex process than value replacement will definitively require XSLT or XQuery.

Comment: @Alejandro: I don't think anyone who has done this with XSLT will ever try to use DOM or other imperative language spaghetti-like tangled code to achieve the same. Any masochists among us? :)

Comment: @All Thanks for the information and idea. I ended up do it in Java instead of XSLT.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <my:reps>
  <repAttr name="name" value="Basic XSLT"/>
  <repAttr name="amount" value="300"/>
  <repAttr name="number" value="20"/>
 </my:reps>

 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
   "@*[name()=document('')/*/my:reps/*/@name]">

   <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select=
    "document('')/*/my:reps/*[@name=name(current())]/@value"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<books>
    <book id="1">
        <title id="11" name="Basic XML"/>
        <price id="12" amount="500"/>
        <quantity id="13" number="10"/>
    </book>
</books>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<books>
   <book id="1">
      <title id="11" name="Basic XSLT"/>
      <price id="12" amount="300"/>
      <quantity id="13" number="20"/>
   </book>
</books>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The identity rule/template copies every node "as-is".
2. The identity template is overriden by a single template matching any attribute whose name can be found as value of one of the `name` attributes of a `repAttr` element that is specified in the `my:reps` element (parameters embeded in the XSLT stylesheet).
3. In this case the attribute is re-created (not copied) with the same name and with the new value, specified in the corresponding `repAttr` element (its `value` attribute).

Comment: great answer as always Dimitre

Answer (score 3):

I cannot "update" the input Xml as XSLT is purely an output driven technology. It creates anew document and cannot modify the existing one.

You could make an almost identical copy but as @Oded comment points out XSLT may be overkill. The xsl would look something like (a modified identity transform)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="title/@Name">
     <!-- insert logic here to change the value as appropriate -->
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```