# Read & Update XML Node element

Tags: java, xml

I am a newbie to Java programming and trying to do an XML read and updation.

I was able to write a program in Java that will create the following XML file. There will be multiple **staff** in a XML file and the **id's** are unique. This example has 2 **staff** items.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<company>
    <staff id="1001">
        <firstname>yong</firstname>
        <lastname>mook kim</lastname>
        <nickname>mkyong</nickname>
        <salary>100000</salary>
    </staff>
    <staff id="2001">
        <firstname>low</firstname>
        <lastname>yin fong</lastname>
        <nickname>fong fong</nickname>
        <salary>200000</salary>
    </staff>
</company>
```

What i want to do is,

Step - 1: ***Read XML*** - based on **ID** provided by user, find the corresponding **staff** element and read it's **salary**.

Step-2: ***Update XML*** - Change the **salary** item for the corresponding **staff** and save the file.

What am looking for is an efficient way of doing this!

Comment: I think you should google parsing or working with XML in java and get some code written. I will be easier for people to help you once you have a more specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple solutions for that:

1. Use JAXB for mapping the XML structure to Java classes. Then you can easily marshal/unmarshal to/from XML;
2. Use XPath/XSLT for quickly accessing the desired XML node in Step #1 and for [updating node content in Step #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351008/xsltcan-i-update-value-in-xml-node-using-xslt);
3. Use one of Java's XML parsers (StAX, DOM, SAX) to read and process the XML.

Option 2 is quick, but I cannot make judgments whether it is the most efficient or not, I guess you can test and take your conclusions.